# Who can see the event/apparent horizon and Hawking effect?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, black-hole-firewall

As I understand, the Hawking effect is related with the presence both event and apparent horizon, i.e. if some kind of horizon exist, a loss/gain of information (unformally speaking) exists.

My question is, concerning the nature of observer, who can be stationary or non-stationary, who will see event horizon + Hawking radiation, and who will see the apparent horizon + Hawking radiation? Is Hawking effect dependent of the motion of the observer?

Answer (score 1):

No observer will ever observe a true horizon because it takes an infinite time to form. All we real observers will ever see is an apparent horizon, though for typical black holes the difference between the real and apparent horizons is extremely small.

The Hawking radiation does depend on the motion of the observer. For example a freely falling observer will observe **no** Hawking radiation. Ron Maimon explains this very nicely in his answer to [Hawking radiation from point of view of a falling observer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/hawking-radiation-from-point-of-view-of-a-falling-observer).