Do black holes evaporate prior to crossing their event horizon?
Bob falls into a black hole, watched by Alice who is far away.
Alice sees Bob asymptotically approach the event horizon while his clock asymptotically approaches 12:00 noon as his image redshifts (illustrated by a recent Veritasium video on black holes.)
From Bob's perspective, he crosses the event horizon at 12:00 according to his clock, not noticing anything special at that time, and proceeds onward.

Let's now take into consideration that at some point in the future, the black hole evaporates due to Hawking radiation.
From Alice's point of view, Bob never passes the event horizon. Bob's clock shows a time prior to 12:00 while the black hole evaporates. The matter/energy he and his ship is composed of is eventually emitted back out to the external environment without ever crossing the black hole's event horizon.
Question
What does Bob see?
Specifically, what occurs first for Bob: 12:00, or completed black hole evaporation?
One way to reconcile these two perspectives is that from Bob's point of view, as 12:00 approaches, he "watches" a sped-up version of the black hole's lifetime as it evaporates due to Hawking radiation, as he gets transformed into radiation along with it, all finishing prior to (what would have been) 12:00 on his clock.
It seems that the usual non-quantum GR description of Bob not noticing anything special happening at 12:00 when crossing the event horizon is no longer accurate when Hawking radiation + black hole evaporation are taken into account.

Other posts have come close to addressing this question, such as Doesn't the Schwarzschild metric combined with Hawking radiation imply that nothing ever gets past the event horizon of a black hole?
however it seems more can be said about reconciling Alice's and Bob's perspectives when taking black hole evaporation into consideration.

Bob doesn't see anything remotely like what Alice sees. He just falls through the horizon without even realizing it, seeing the BH fill more of his view but not all of it, until he gets torn apart

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175265/123208

Isn't this a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3706/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627370/

Does this answer your question? Falling into an evaporating black hole

@RC_23 that is the description commonly given in the eternal BH scenario. The spacetime of an evaporating BH is fundamentally different. One of the essential issues being explored in this question is reconciling the order of events in Alice's frame of reference with Bob's. In Alice's frame, BH evaporation appears to occur prior to Bob's clock striking 12:00. Does your answer imply that the order of these two events are reversed in Bob's frame? If Bob is still intact at 12:00:01 within the event horizon, what point in spacetime does that correspond to in Alice's coordinate system?

If it evaporates before Bob falls in then he and Alice will be in the same reference frame.


Let's now take into consideration that at some point in the future, the black hole evaporates due to Hawking radiation.
From Alice's point of view, Bob never passes the event horizon.

This last statement is not correct. The issue is that you are taking reasoning based on the eternal black hole Schwarzschild coordinates and trying to apply that to an evaporating black hole. An evaporating black hole and an eternal black hole are completely different spacetimes, and both Schwarzschild coordinates and the behavior of geodesics are different in the different spacetimes.
See “Black Hole - Never Forms, or Never Evaporates”. In particular, Figure 3 shows that, in an evaporating spacetime that satisfies the usual energy conditions, null geodesics do not cross the horizon, but become outgoing null geodesics after the evaporation.
So if Bob is continually emitting a signal of his proper time then his signals will escape and he, staying within his own light cone, must also escape. His 12:00 signal will arrive to Alice in finite time, as will all subsequent signals.
This is physically different from the eternal black hole where Alice would continue to receive signals from Bob forever, all of which would show finite proper time from Bob.
Note that the above will not constrain spacetimes that violate one or more of the usual energy conditions. Such might have timelike paths that enter the horizon and meet the singularity before it evaporates.

Specifically, what occurs first for Bob: 12:00, or completed black hole evaporation?

If Bob crosses the event horizon at 12:00 proper time then he will hit the singularity before it evaporates. If he escapes, then light could also escape, so he did not cross the horizon.

"This is physically different from the eternal black hole where Alice would continue to receive signals from Bob forever, all of which would show finite proper time from Bob." If Bob sent signals at regular intervals, isn't it true that he would have sent only a finite number of them before passing the event horizon and therefore Alice would eventually stop receiving them? (even ignoring the fading of their intensity)

@D.Halsey I was explicitly speaking of continuous signals. Not discrete signals at regular intervals

I'm still digesting the paper, but it does say "In Sec.II B the solution will be applied to show that the light-cone forbids anything to encounter the horizon of an evaporating BH before it vanished" consistent with your comment about Figure 3. This seems to imply that Bob avoids crossing the event horizon, and "survives" the black hole evaporation. Thus Alice will continue to receive signals from Bob after 12:00 his time. I'm having trouble reconciling this with: "she will receive no more signals from Bob". What do you think Bob experiences from 12:00 onward his time with the evaporating BH?

@Matt you are right. I think I misunderstood the figure. I was thinking that the ingoing lines were a selected subset that miss the horizon. It looks like the author says all Ingoing light misses the horizon. I will revise shortly

Interesting. I haven't read the paper (yet), but I see that it's only been cited 3 times in a dozen years, and I can't find any other papers by that author on arXiv.

@Matt The Figure 3 is misleading. While null geodesics don’t cross the horizon, they carry out a zero energy after the evaporation. Their direction is theoretically correct, but they don’t actually exist, because the energy of everything (including light) near the horizon evaporates via the Hawking radiation. The same happens to timelike geodesics. Bob’s experience ends at noon by his clock at the moment when the black hole disappears in the final evaporation. The details of how this happens are unknown since they are a subject of the Information Paradox.

@safesphere geodesics parallel transport their four momentum. You cannot parallel transport any non-zero vector to a zero vector

@Dale Correct and this is exactly the problem with Figure 3. All energy of the infalling photon is emitted out by the Hawking radiation, so the photon cannot continue on the outgoing geodesic. One well known proposal to resolve this is that the geodesics terminate in the firewall singularity just outside the horizon, but the exact mechanism is unclear.

@safesphere “all of the energy of the infalling photon is emitted out by the Hawking radiation”. That cannot happen on a geodesic as it would not parallel transport its four momentum. There is no firewall singularity in this solution (this solution obeys the energy conditions while the firewall proposal violates them). The figure is not misleading, the spacetime simply doesn’t have the feature you assume it does

@Dale I still don’t get what your objection is. Are you saying that the energy of the infalling photon doesn’t evaporate or that the infalling photon doesn’t follow a geodesic? The former contradicts Hawking; the latter contradicts Figure 3 in this paper.

@safesphere I am saying the former. As to whether it contradicts Hawking or not depends on your point of view. Hawking’s solution violates the usual energy conditions. This one does not. So I would say that they are talking about slightly different things rather than that it is a contradiction. But if you want to call that a contradiction, then you are welcome to do so. I don’t feel it is helpful to call it a contradiction, but you may take a narrower view on what qualifies as an evaporating black hole. In my view I do not limit evaporating spacetimes to only Hawking’s form

@Dale Thanks for clarifying your view.

@Dale I'd like to accept this answer, but I have problems with the first and last paragraphs: This last statement is not correct. The issue is that you are taking reasoning based on the eternal black hole Schwarzschild coordinates and trying to apply that to an evaporating black hole. Is it really incorrect to say that "From Alice's point of view, Bob never passes the event horizon."? I don't see any contradiction between what you and I are saying. In the last paragraph why bother considering if Bob crosses the event horizon, since we know that doesn't happen based on your answer?

@Matt we know that he doesn’t cross the horizon in spacetimes that satisfy the various energy conditions. In other spacetimes, however, that is not the case. In such spacetimes he can cross the horizon, and the horizon ends at a specific time. So his crossing cannot happen at a later time even from her perspective, in such spacetimes.
