# Measuring Hawking radiation after the coordinate transformation

Tags: gravity, reference-frames, hawking-radiation

If an observer can measure the Hawking radiation or surface gravity in his co-moving/rest frame, what happens when we make a coordinate transformation to a moving frame of reference? Can we make such coordinate transformation that the Hawking radiation and surface gravity are equal to zero in the moving frame (and vice versa)?

Edit: I had in mind inertial frames when I asked the question.

Comment: We can not transform the radiation away because that would violate the third law of thermodynamics (the local speed of light being a constant guarantees that, too... no observer can outrun photons). The free falling observer, on the other hand, does, to first order, not feel the gravity.

Comment: Does that mean that the Hawking radiation can't be measured/seen by the free falling observer?

Comment: See [Hawking radiation from point of view of a falling observer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/hawking-radiation-from-point-of-view-of-a-falling-observer).

Comment: No, it means quite the opposite. While I am not a specialist, I would say you can safely discount any analysis that violates the third law. An observer in orbit around a black hole is freely falling, by the way, so that is not a criterion to eliminate Hawking radiation by any means.