# Can you experience multiple points in time at a specific point in time?

Tags: spacetime, speed-of-light, time, spacetime-dimensions

So from my understanding, light takes time to travel to our eyes. So everything we see is from the past, right? So does that mean that at a specific point in time, we are seeing simultaneously a point at 1 second ago at a 1 light second distance, a point at 2 second ago at a 2 light second distance, and so on. So does that mean that multiple points in time exist enter our eyes at the same time, even if they are from different points in space?

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/has-everything-we-see-happened-in-the-past)

Comment: *multiple points in time exist enter our eyes at the same time* Points in time aren’t entering your eyes; light emitted at different points in time is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you see objects (located at different distances from you)
where and how they were at different points in the past.

Example: At the same time you see

- the moon ($380.000$ km away) where it was $1.3$ seconds ago,
- Jupiter (a planet $780$ million km away) where it was $40$ minutes ago,
- and Vega (a star $25$ light years away) where it was $25$ years ago.